# Is this a safe way of passing temporary object or not

Tags: c++, temporary

```
m_sUser.compareNoCase(pmA2U("pmkerberosuser").buffer())
```

pmA2U returns an object by value which has a member function buffer() for accessing its internal buffer. Will the temporary object constructed for the return value of pmA2U survive till the enclosing functioin compareNoCase is completed, to which it is passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A temporary lasts until the end of the *full expression* that creates it. In this case, the full expression is the entire statement, so it will last until after the function returns.

Make sure the function doesn't store a pointer or reference to the buffer anywhere, since that would be invalidated shortly after it returns.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary object constructed for the return value of `pmA2U()` will survive until the enclosing functioin `compareNoCase()` is completed.